# SQL HASHBYTES function returns weird output when used in CASE WHEN/IIF

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, hashbytes

I have written a stored procedure that hashes the value of a certain column. I need to use this HASHBYTES function in a CASE WHEN or IIF statement, like this:

```
DECLARE @Hash varchar(255) = 'testvalue'
SELECT    IIF(1=1, HASHBYTES('SHA1',@Hash), @Hash)
SELECT CASE WHEN 1=1 THEN HASHBYTES('SHA1',@Hash) END  AS Hashcolumn
```

I can't get my head around why I get different outputs from above queries? it seems that whenever I add an ELSE in the CASE WHEN / IIF statement, it returns a string of weird characters (like `ü<þ+OUL'RDOk{­\Ìø` in above example).

Can anyone tell me why this is happening? I need to use the CASE WHEN or IIF.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 5):

`IIF` returns the data type with the [highest precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) from the types in true_value and false_value. In this case, it's `@Hash1` which is `varchar(255)` so your result is getting cast to `varchar(255)`. See below.

```
DECLARE @Hash varchar(255) = 'testvalue'
SELECT cast(HASHBYTES('SHA1',@Hash) as varchar(255))
```

Similarly, `CASE` works the same way. However, if you don't add an `ELSE` or another `WHEN` that would conflict with the data type, it will work. This is because an `ELSE NULL` is implied. i.e.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 1=1 THEN HASHBYTES('SHA1',@Hash) END
```

However, if you add another check, then precedence kicks in, and it will be converted.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 1=1 THEN HASHBYTES('SHA1',@Hash) WHEN 1=2 THEN @Hash END AS Hashcolumn 
SELECT CASE WHEN 1=1 THEN HASHBYTES('SHA1',@Hash) ELSE @Hash END AS Hashcolumn
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I've posted a new comment, can you take a look at that? I still find it very weird.

Comment: I've answered your original question, but your comments on your answer below are confusing for me. I'm not sure what the ultimate goal is here and why an `IIF` or `CASE` is needed. I think you should open a new question for your new problem.

Comment: The idea is that I hash the data in the column if 1=1 (this is ofcourse another condition, but it doesn't matter), else just show the default record within the column, but I guess this is not possible, as the default record in the column is always varchar and it will be overruled by data precedence if I understand it right.

Comment: you are correct in your last statement. You can do this one other way, but I'd need to know the real purpose / use case, as another solution may not work for your simple example.

Comment: I'm very interested in the other way. Basically what the stored procedure does is the following:

1. Bulk insert a CSV file
2. Take first row based on CRLF and take comma delimited headers 
3. Create a temp table from these headers
4. Hash the data in column X (based on inputparameter). If columname from csv = columname, then hash the data in that column. Otherwise just return column values.

Does that make any sense? All I really need is a way to bypass the examples, which is the exact problem. I need to either hash or show normal column data(which is always varchar)

Comment: Unfortunately that’s not enough information. We would need the entire code set. I would accept this answer and open a new one so it gets more attention @ImperialBert

Comment: The examples in my main post is exactly what the stored procedure does and where it goes wrong. I just need these examples to work. The entire stored procedure is too long to post here I'm afraid. I just need the CASE WHEN to work WITH an extra WHEN / ELSE statement. Also, the 1=1 is ALWAYS varbinary, and the 1=2 is ALWAYS varchar. Hope you can help me to "bypass" the data precedence in my example. The hash can also be returned as a string btw, it doesn't matter, as the hash will be exported into a CSV file, just to mask the data in that certain column.

Comment: What I’m saying @ImperialBert  is that it’s not enough for me unfortunately and it’s unlikely that this question gets viewed much more so you’d have a better chance of opening a new question. Why are you so against that? This was a good question that got upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

The output of a select query is a virtual table. In a relational db a column of a table is constrained to single data type.. so here what happens is implicit conversion is being done by the server engine inorder to render a sigle type and hence weird characters are returned.

The nature of conversion is as @scsimon says it follows highest precedence order.

The following query should help.

```
DECLARE @Hash varchar(255) = 'testvalue'
SELECT    IIF(1=1, CONVERT(VARCHAR(255),HASHBYTES('SHA1',@Hash),2), @Hash)
SELECT CASE WHEN 1=2 THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(255),HASHBYTES('SHA1',@Hash),2) 
      ELSE @Hash END  AS Hashcolumn
```